# managedObject property as datasource for uitableview

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, ios7, nsmanagedobject

I have a managed object "camera" which contains a "rolls" property. I would like to make a table of rolls.

Can I use the rolls property of the camera object as the datasource for a table rather than using a fetchedResultsController with a camera predicate in order to get the rolls for a specific camera?

Would I use the property as is or would I need to put it in a mutable array or something like that?

Comment: 1->many relationship properties return an NSSet which is unordered. To ensure your rows remain fixed you would need to copy Roll entities into an array sorted on a property of the Rolls entity. Why do you not want to use a fetched results controller - would seem a good solution.

Comment: @MarkWoollard Thanks. It seems odd to me since the object already has the data I'm looking for that I should need to make a fetch for it. But maybe not since I need to jump through a lot of hoops just to make it datasource material

Comment: You could obtain NSArray of Rolls from Camera as follows - NSArray *rolls = [camera.rolls sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:@[[NSSortDescriptor sortDescritorWithKey:@"key" ascending:YES]]]; (adjust @"key" and YES for your requirements, key is a property of Rolls entity).